# How to log properly in webflux when using Schedulers.boundedElastic()?

Tags: java, asynchronous, logging, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have below code and none of the loggers are getting printed.

- I tried without Schedulers.boundedElastic(), then it works fine.
- I also tried with Schedulers.boundedElastic() and Thread.sleep outside subscribe, then it works.

**Not working:**

```
class Foo1 {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo1.class);

    @Test
    public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
        Mono.just("Input Data").flatMap(msg -> {
            try {
                logger.info("Message input in logger");
                // Some functionality
                return Mono.just("Message processed");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.toString());
                return Mono.just("Message not processed");
            }
        }).doOnNext(res -> logger.info(res)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .subscribe(c -> logger.info("subscribe completed"));
    }
}
```

**Working**

```
class Foo1 {
        private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo1.class);
    
        @Test
        public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
            Mono.just("Input Data").flatMap(msg -> {
                try {
                    logger.info("Message input in logger");
                    // Some functionality
                    return Mono.just("Message processed");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e.toString());
                    return Mono.just("Message not processed");
                }
            }).subscribe(c -> logger.info("subscribe completed"));
        }
    }
```

I want to execute the logic async, but logs should be printed.

How to achive this without losing async functionality and without using Thread.sleep explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `block` but not `subscribe`, Or you can subscribe with `.doFinally(sig -> latch.countDown())`.